# Next js Server briefly start then exits

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

running `next dev` - the server starts briefly and then closes.

```
> next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

and then it exits.
I'm using windows [Screenshot of the CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mkoq.png)

I used this command as of today

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

and updating node stable version  18.14.2 + additional features while installing , and installing windows WSL since the docs mention this

```
System Requirements

Node.js 14.6.0 or newer
MacOS,>>>>>>>> Windows (including WSL) <<<<<<<<, and Linux are supported
```

i've tried localhost:3000 on the browser while the server was "Up" and kept refreshing with no response

tried to update node

deleted node_modules then did `npm i` still the same problem.

installed windows WSL

how do i make this work ?

Comment: you either have a bug in your code, or your machine is running out of memory. you should share the git repo or create a reproducible code repo

Comment: the main reason **may** be you are low on memory, this happens during the build phase too.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Installing the latest version of nextjs resolved my issue:

npm install next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

`Date: 18 March 2023`

☠️I also faced the same problem after creating the app using the latest version of `nextjs`.

*And I couldn't solve it even after spending a lot of time*

**✅Later I install the `old version` of nextjs and the server starts successfully and doesn't stop automatically.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From experience the `ready - started server` is just the first step. Once you request a page, it then runs the full build process to generate the static files. There should be additional output listing out all the routes and the method used to build each route. I would make the request and let it spin for a couple minutes, as even my small site (daktoalewallen.me) in dev mode usually takes a minute or so to compile on first run.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Windows. Reinstall node and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I ran to the same issue and it was because of having a strange issue with the default PORT 3000 when I made the app running on another PORT it worked, you can try this

update this line in your `package.json` file

```json
"dev": "next dev -p 4000",
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for most cases;

1. upgrade to the latest LTS version of node js from here https://nodejs.org/en
2. run `npm i -g npm@latest` to upgrade npm to the latest version

Note: sometimes npm will warn about missing dependencies. In such cases, follow the prompts to download

For some cases you might have to do the following for your project;

3. remove package-lock.json file and regenerate it with the newer version of your package manager in (2) above
4. run `npm install`
5. run your project using `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be for infinite reasons, but I couldn't find a way to display a good stacktrace for this. So I'm posting here one of the many possible scenarios.

Check your `package.json` file for inconsistencies in dependencies.

In my case I had installed node `v20.3.0` and I had on my `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.3.1",
    ...
```

So the node versions didn't match.

Make sure thet if you have that version installed is the one set to be the default one too.

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm i next@latest` and restarting the server worked for me